# Injecting Java Bytecode in XML for harmful purposes

Tags: java, xml, security, jaxb, jax-rs

So I have been thinking whether there is a way to send an XML such that the XML contains code in (bytecode) that will be unintentionally executed by the JVM. I am using java so I think uncompiled code will not work. I think I need to inject bytecode in the XML to trick the JVM? I want to try to make sure that the web service that I am building is secure. I am using JAXB for xml marshalling unmarshalling and Jersey as the web service handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unintentionally?  I don't think so.

The JAXB marshaller is going to deserialize XML values into the state of a given object, but the class and its behavior will be decided by you.  I don't see sending raw bytecode in the XML and doing anything harmful with it.

You could send a JSON object that your Java object could execute using Rhino, but that's hardly unintentional.

Your service might have other security issues, but Java byte code injection attack isn't one of them.

You should be validating all data sent to you before binding, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

About the only xml related vulnerability (i'm aware of) is "external entities", you can read up on that [here](http://securitytracker.com/id?1019292).  pretty sure the jdk has external entity handling disabled by default these days.

Answer (score 1):

XML is data, and it's very unlikely that any recipient is going to try to execute it.

But of course, some XML vocabularies use the data to contain what you can think of as instructions to perform an action, and the recipient might then be fooled into performing inappropriate actions, which you could consider to be a security problem. This vulnerability is not at the level of XML, it is at the level of the application protocol (the vocabulary). The attack would have to use instructions that make sense in the context of this protocol, which is much more likely to be something like `<employee action="delete"/>` than something at the level of bytecode.